# how to use two $.post methods very well for give data from 2 different database

Tags: php, jquery

```
 function ChangeGallery(){
    var GalleryName = $('.SubSubGalleryLock').text();

    /*Send string to Data1.php and include Tags from Database*/
    $.post("Data1.php", {  Sections: GalleryName  },
    function(data){
         $(".IncludeData").append(data);
    }); 

    /*send string to Data2.php and include Events data from Database*/
    $.post("Data2.php",{  GallerySec: GalleryName  },
    function(response){
         /*when i use alert method, this function works very well, why?*/
         alert('SomeString');
     var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
         var ImageID  = data[0];
         var ImageSrc = data[1];
     $(ImageID).click(function(){
        $(".LargeImage").attr('src', ImageSrc);
     });
     });
};
```

in Data1.php

```
  /*give data from database1 and print to HTML File*/
  if ($_POST['Sections']) == "String")
  {  $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table1");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
  { echo $row['Tags']; }
```

in Data2.php

```
  /*give data from database2 and Use for events*/
  if ($_POST['GallerySec']) == "String")
  {  $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table2");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
  { echo json_encode($row); }
```

in Client side when i use it then Data1.php works very well but Data2.php only when i write an

```
alert('Some stringh');
```

after

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```

line, it's work well, why? what's due to this problem?

Comment: You want to change image source after `ImageID ` gets cicked?

Comment: it's works truly but when i use alert() method

Comment: Works means image source changed if the alert statement is there?

Comment: when i use alert statement then function(response) give data from database very well, but when i don't use it, it's not work

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use two $.post methods very well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709765/how-to-use-two-post-methods-very-well)

Comment: afaf12 I think I don't understand your mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you need the second `.post()` to be processed AFTER the first `.post()` and when you put the `alert()` in, that guarantees that it will go in that order, but without the `alert()`, it is a race condition and depends upon which `.post()` returns quicker.

There are a couple ways to fix the sequencing.  The most straightforward is to start the second `.post()` from the success handler of the first so that you know the first has already completed.

You can also use jQuery promises or you could use your own flags to keep track of which has finished and call the last bit of code only when both have finished.

Here's how you would start the second `.post()` from the success handler of the first to guarantee the order:

```
function ChangeGallery(){
    var GalleryName = $('.SubSubGalleryLock').text();

    /*Send string to Data1.php and include Tags from Database*/
    $.post("Data1.php", {  Sections: GalleryName  },
    function(data){
         $(".IncludeData").append(data);
        /*send string to Data2.php and include Events data from Database*/
        $.post("Data2.php",{  GallerySec: GalleryName  },
            function(response){
                var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                var ImageID  = data[0];
                var ImageSrc = data[1];
                $(ImageID).click(function(){
                    $(".LargeImage").attr('src', ImageSrc);
                });
         }); 
     });
};
```

Comment: AFTER mean is I create a separate function for use second .post()?

Comment: what's jQuery promises?

Comment: @MojtabaSh - jQuery promises are fully described in the jQuery documentation.

Comment: @MojtabaSh - see the code I added to my answer for how to sequence the second `.post()` to be AFTER the first.

Comment: Many Thanks @friend00 - it's very good way for correct that bug